# How to externalize a url in Spring Boot to application.properties file?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a REST consumer class with "url" variable. Instead of typing the endpoint url directly to the variable, I would like to externalize the actual url string to e.g. the application.properties file. So how do I then reference to the url string from the variable in code?

I know, a super easy question but I just couldn't find anything from google :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another, more type-safe way of doing this in SpringBoot is using `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="some_prefix")`. You declare your variable in application.properties `endpoint.url=example.com`. Then in Your class you do something like:

```
@Service
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="endpoint")
public class exampleClass {
    private String url; //variable name has to match name of the variable definied in application.properties

    //getter and setter for url is mandatory!
}
```

Comment: Didn't know about that, looks quite interesting... However `setters` [don't seem to be required](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-loading-yaml), that's a good point.

Answer (score 5):

Declare it in *application.properties*:

```
service.url=http://myservice.com:8080
```

Then, you are supposed to have a `@Service` including a [`RestTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) or similar to access the endpoint:

```
@Service
public class RemoteAccessService{

    private RestTemplate template;

    private String baseUrl;

    @Autowired
    public RemoteAccessService(RestTemplate template, @Value("${service.url}") baseUrl){
        this.template = template;
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    }

    public String grabResult(){
        return template.getForObject(baseUrl+"/hotels/{hotel}/bookings/{booking}", String.class, "42", "21");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using application.yml file, will make it simpler then

```
services:
  service: ${https://requiredUrl}
```

and in your class file

```
@Value("${services.service}")
private String reqUrl;
```

Comment: how to the get value of this ${https://requiredUrl} at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

in the application.properties
[image]

in the controller or service refer like this

[image]